# Get Real time Analytics Data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to get analytics data of each user of my website. I know that google analytics provide data user wise but I am not able to export that data using API. I want real time user wise data with export feature to save it in my database. I have gone through many platform like mouseflow but they do not provide data user wise. Is anyone have idea how can I implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how to get data from Google Real Time API (with Google Apps Script):
https://www.appsscript.it/tutorial/utilizzare-le-real-time-reporting-api-di-google-analytics-con-apps-script/

Comment: This is not giving data user wise. As I mentioned in my question that I want data with their logged in ids but the link you provided is giving collective data of users.

Comment: In this case you can't. In this page you can find all the dimensions and metrics available through the Real Time Reporting API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets